# Как вывести function значение с запросом MySQL в PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, веб-программирование

### Как вывести function значение с запросом MySQL в PHP?

Сам код:

```
function get_valplusid_all() {
global $db;
$singles = $db->query("SELECT MAX(id) + 1 FROM singles"); // Пагинация
return $singles; }
```

Как вывести полученное значение в **обычный input value?**

```
<div class="col-12">
<input type="number" class="form__input" name="idfilm" value="">
</div>
```

Comment: `<?php echo 1 ; ?>`

Comment: @AlexGlebe чего?

Comment: `value="<?php echo 1 ; ?>"`

Comment: @AlexGlebe почему echo 1?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Для начала необходимо понять что возвращает `$singles`.
Если число - `<?php echo get_valplusid_all(); ?>`
Если массив, необходимо получить значение - `return $singles[0];` и в шаблоне вызываем `<?php echo get_valplusid_all(); ?>`

Comment: Мне необходимо просто вывести этот запрос `$singles = $db->query("SELECT MAX(id) + 1 FROM singles");` в input, если в input вставлю `?php echo get_valplusid_all(); ?>` ничего не выводится

Comment: `$singles` что возвращает? число?

Comment: да, число. А как вывести в input?

Comment: value="<?php echo get_valplusid_all(); ?> "

Comment: Не выводится число и остальной код исчезнает. Может нужно обработать как то запрос этот чтобы вывести число? По Типу.. `<?php $singles = get_singles_all(); foreach ($singles as $single) { ?>`

Comment: Сработало!! спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!